# Pulling programs from system tray in windows?

Tags: c, windows, winapi, system-tray

I'm currently updating an old program written in C that essential acts as a window manager for windows. I'm trying to add some new functionality, more specifically a system tray. Is there any way I can access the programs that are currently in the windows system trays, so I can place them on my custom taskbar?

Comment: There's actually no such thing as the system tray. I guess you mean the notification area. And it doesn't contain programs. It contains items represented by icons. One process can have multiple items. What exactly do you want to do with the notification area? What information do you need?

Comment: It sounds like he wants to clone the notification area in his own shell replacement.

Comment: There is no Win32 API that exposes access to the icons of the Taskbar's notification area.  You would have to hook into the taskbar window itself to intercept the `WM_COPYDATA` message that `Shell_NotifyIcon()` uses to manage the icons.  Then you can copy their details into your window manager as needed.  The window message data is not documented by MSDN, but is documented on various online sites if you search around.

Comment: Yeah, thats exactly what I'm looking for. So I have to use a hook?